# How to get the health status of a single index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am using elasticsearch 5.6.16. I know about the cluster health and cat health APIs which come bundled with elasticsearch 5.6

I want to know the status of a particular index found inside my elasticsearch local instance. The issue with cluster health or cat health API is that they return the health status of all the indices present inside the elasticsearch instance and I only want to get the health status of a particular instance.

Is there a way by which I can the health status of a single index only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cluster Health API only for specific index as well:

> The cluster health API returns a simple status on the health of the
> cluster. You can also use the API to get the health status of only
> specified data streams and indices.

```
GET /_cluster/health/my-index-000001
```

Above request will return only information about `my-index-000001` index.